# How great can gods have sense for humor?

Tags: gods

As I mentioned in some previous questions or answers on them, I read not only books of Discworld series. And if there is something why I like it, it is Death's sense for humor and interest in people.

And I decided to use it for my gods.

So, they are ready to help *atheist* instead anybody else who believes in them *too much* (who prays to them ritually or so), just to make believers angry (it is reference to joke *Why gods like atheists? Because they don't bother them with requests*).

Or elsewhere, the Evil the Rider (like Pratchett's Death, but he is one of lower gods) goes to help to fight against arch-villains with words *it is hard to stay out of humain affairs in whiles of great battles*.

Or The One heard woman to say *Gods, please, kill him earlier I shall kill him* and gave that woman very sharp axe.

---

But where can gods' sense for humor end? How great sense for humor can gods have?

Comment: Where does an 800 pound Grizzly bear take a dump? Anywhere it wants to. How great a sense of humor can all-powerful gods have? As much as they want to.

Comment: This is a vague question. I almost answered with Anselm's [Ontological Argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontological_argument) (even though it is logically flawed): "that than which nothing greater can be thought". In other words, your god's would have the greatest sense of humor you can imagine. This is highly subjective, and why I've down-voted your question.

Comment: **When dealing with any form of imaginative creation** (not a comment on whether or not a god exists, just assuming you don't have some inside knowledge the rest of us missed) **you are the only one to say what they can or cannot have.**

Comment: Japanese riddle (or so it was claimed): "Q: How do you make God laugh? A: Tell him your plans for the future."

Answer (score 2):

Anything you wish to dream up.

Heck, in Norse mythology, Thor dresses up as a woman to go "marry" a giant. In Greek mythology, Poseidon sired a horse, and in Norse mythology again, Loki was the mom of the horse. Weird family relations abound. There's multiple species. And the gods in those stories can have a sense of humor too, or at least of irony.

Mythology gets *weird*, and really, a rather large, possibly deadly sense of humor is not going to be the strangest thing out there. If you want to do it, do it - you're the author. Also, I mean, if the gods in your story have created everything, then they've created humor, and they define the limits for it...

Aside from all that, perhaps what you're meaning to ask is "When does it get old?" And for that, I'd say, keep it in the attitude of the gods, make it normal, perhaps, but try not to have every page contain a godly joke.

Answer (score -1):

If gods exist in your setting, then they are likely to be the ones who "created" humanity... Just to introduce them to millions of ways to die painfully or unreasonable.

The irony is strong within them and so is their sense of humour.